# What is wrong with my cursor in the shading work space

Tags: shaders

There is something wrong with my cursor in the shading workspace it is a white hole
and I can't select anything it only selects things when you hold the right-click button on your mouse and I don't want that I want a normal cursor and I know I messed up but I can't find error.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LxJWqq3Z" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LxJWqq3Z/)

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally switched to *Circle Select*.

To select a different mode, click and hold the tool icon.
Or press <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle between different select modes.

[image]